# Cleaner way of handling Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing several functions that take different types of parameters. As such, it's much simpler to just do:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
}
```

...than to try to handle all the different possibilities directly in the parameter field of the function declaration, e.g.:

```
var myFunc = function(param1, param2, param3) {
    if (param3) {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` adds a lot to the code though, and reduces readability. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to write a helper function that could accomplish the same thing as `Array.prototype.slice.call()`, but cleaner and easier to read. I was trying something like:

```
var parseArgs = function() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
}

var foo = function() {
    console.log(parseArgs(arguments))
}

foo('one', 'two', 'three')
// [Arguments, ['one', 'two', 'three']]
```

But obviously that doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure about your exact use case but maybe the option object pattern is a better choice, e.g.: `function foo(o) { log(o.name) }    foo({ name: "Bar" })`

Comment: @lleaff this needs to be more flexible than that unfortunately 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments object of `foo` and slice only that, like this

```
function parseArgs(args) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(args);
}
```

When you use `arguments` inside `parseArgs` it will refer to the arguments received by that function only not the one which `foo` received.

---

In ECMA Script 2015, you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) on `arguments` object directly, like this

```
function foo() {
    console.log(Array.from(arguments));
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can keep the `parseArgs` as it is and spread the `arguments` over `parseArgs` in ECMA Script 2015, like this

```
function parseArgs() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

function foo() {
    console.log(parseArgs(...arguments));
}
```

This basically means that you are spreading the `arguments` received by `foo` and passing them over to `parseArgs` so that it will also receive the same arguments.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to write `Array.prototype.slice.call(args)` everytime you can do:

```
var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

And then you can use it anywhere like:

```
function fn(){
    var arr = slice(arguments);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Node.js though, so while this would work in a single script, I can't see it working with module.exports()?

Comment: It should work on Node too. Unless you do something weird with their globals.

Comment: Depends I guess where I load the module where it's implemented. If I do that before I load any other modules that depend on it, it would probably work.

Comment: @remus This also will work, because this doesn't use any browser/node specific feature :-)

Comment: Oh, yeah I realize it's not node-specific.

Answer (score 3):

A few shorthands for converting array-like objects to actual arrays in JS:

Alias `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
(function (slice) {
  ...your code...
  function someFunction() {
    var args = slice.call(arguments);
    ...
  }
  ...
}(Array.prototype.slice));
```

Use `[].slice`:

```
function someFunction() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
}
```

Create your own slice (you tried this but had an error in the arguments):

```
function slice(arr) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr);
}
function someFunction() {
  var args = slice(arguments);
}
```

Use the modern [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (be sure to polyfill for backwards compatibility):

```
function someFunction() {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
}
```

If you're in an environment where you can safely use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), then there is no need for any call to `slice`:

```
function someFunction() {
  var args = [...arguments];
}
```

Comment: Or, `var args = [...arguments];`.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var parseArgs = function(args) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(args)
}

var foo = function() {
    console.log(parseArgs(arguments))
}

foo('one', 'two', 'three')
```

This way you parse the actual arguments `array`

Comment: Alternatively, you could cache `slice` to avoid the performance hit of indirection on every call: `var slice = Array.prototype.slice;`. Or just bind everything directly once: `var parseArgs = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to use `arguments` in a way that causes the function to be unoptimizable. One must be extremely careful when using `arguments`.

From arguments object on  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> **Important:** You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in JavaScript engines (V8 for example). Instead, try constructing a new array by iterating through the arguments object.

As Node.js uses V8 you probably want to do something like this:

```js
function parseArgs() {
  var args = new Array(arguments.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    args[i] = arguments[i];
  }
  return args;
}

function myFunc() {
  var args = parseArgs.apply(null, arguments);
  console.log(args); // => [1,2,3]
}

myFunc(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of all of this - hence why I'm using the recommended approach from MDN of Array.prototype.slice.call()

Comment: @remus, MDN recommends *against* using `Array.prototype.slice.call` for performance optimization reasons. Of course, it's rarely likely that `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` is a bottleneck, so I wouldn't really worry much about this particular issue.

Comment: It's interesting, the MDN warning is a bit ambiguous; it sounds more like they're saying you shouldn't use `arguments.slice()` directly. I suppose I misinterpreted it.

Comment: @brandonscript There _is no `arguments.slice`_, so you cannot call it directly. `slice` is an array method, which arguments is not, which is the whole reason why you are converting `arguments` to an array in the first place. So it's not ambiguous at all. Just try this in your console: `(function (){ return arguments.slice(); })(1,2,3)`