# Understanding Function.call.bind - step-by-step

Tags: javascript

Everything started with this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797268/cleaner-way-of-handling-array-prototype-slice-callarguments)

Then an answer from @MinusFour

```
var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

I wanted to understand, whats happening under the hood, 
my curiosity hence this Question.

what to achieve ? understanding of "`Function.call.bind`".

Step-by-step approach for the same

Started with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

**NOTE : I am using NodeJS here**

**1)**

```
var adder = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
console.log(adder(2, 6));
```

**OUTPUT **

```
8
```

This is expected, Nothing Fancy

**2)**

This is our end goal , calling function `myFunc` from the bounded
function (`Function.call.bind(myFunc)`)

```
function myFunc(a, b) {
    console.log(arguments.length, a, b, a + b);
}
```

**3)**

```
var adder = Function(myFunc);
console.log(adder.toString())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
function anonymous() { function myFunc(a, b) {   console.log(a + b); } }
```

Expected! above code does nothing, because i am calling 'anonymous' ,
and it does nothing.

**4)**

```
var adder = Function.call(myFunc);
console.log(adder.toString())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
function anonymous() {

}
```

Expected!.  `'.call'`  calls `'Function'`, with `'this'` set to `'myFunc'`  and with out any param or function body. so an empty anonymous function is  the output. Now, I can do `"var adder = Function.call(myFunc,myFunc);"`   to create the same function from step-3

So far so good

**5)**

```
var adder = Function.call.bind(myFunc);
console.log(adder.toString())   
adder(2,6);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
function () { [native code] }
1 6 undefined NaN
```

Here first param is not passed to the `'myFunc'` function. 
this is taken as `'this'` for function `'adder'` (the bounded `Function.call`) ?

Now I understand(or did I misunderstood?) until now, but then
How does below code works ?

```
var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
function fn(){
    var arr = slice(arguments);
}
```

in my case first param to adder is discarded(or `Function.call` consider it as `'this'` for it), same should happen with `slice` above  right ?

**Anyway, i wanted to document it for a reference**

Comment: It's absolutely fine (encouraged, even) to answer your own question, but it has to be like on the *Jeopardy!* game show: Post your question as a *question*, and if you have an answer, post that as an *answer*. Right now it's hard to tell what your question is, and hard to tell whether you feel you already have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you've gone off in slightly the wrong direction. This line:

```
var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

never calls `Function` and never arranges for it to be called later. The only thing `Function` is being used for there is its `call` property. `Function` could have been `Object` or `Date` or `RegExp` or any other function, or could have been `Function.prototype`; doesn't matter. `Function.prototype` would have been more direct and possibly less confusing.

This is a bit tricky to explain because it involves two layers of dealing with `this`, where `this` is different things at different times:

The `call` function calls functions with a specific `this` value you give it as its first argument, passing along any other arguments you give it. For example:

```
function foo(arg) {
    console.log("this.name = " + this.name + ", arg = " + arg);
}
var obj = {name: "bar"};
foo.call(obj, "glarb"); // "this.name = bar, arg = glarb"
```

There, because we called `call` on `foo`, `call` called `foo` with `this` set to `obj` and passing along the `"glarb"` argment.

`call` knows what function it should call based on what `this` is during the `call` call. `foo.call` sets `this` during `call` to `foo`. That can be confusing, so let's diagram it:

- `foo.call(obj, "glarb")` calls `call`:

  - `call` sees `this = foo` and the arguments `obj` and `"glarb"`
  - `call` calls `this` (which is `foo`):

    - `foo` sees `this = obj` and the single argument `"glarb"`

With regard to `slice`, you normally see `call` used with it used to create an array from something array-*like* that isn't really an array:

```
var divArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));
```

or

```
var divArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));
```

There, we call `call` with `this` set to `Array.prototype.slice` (or `[].slice`, which is the same function) and passing in the collection returned by `querySelectorAll` as the first argument. `call` calls the function it sees as `this`, using its first argument as `this` for that call, and passing along any others.

So that's the first layer of `this` stuff.

`bind` is another function that functions have, and it's similar to `call` but different: Where `call` *calls* the target function with a given `this` and arguments, `bind` creates and returns a *new* function that will do that if you call it. Going back to our `foo` example:

```
function foo(arg) {
    console.log("this.name = " + this.name + ", arg = " + arg);
}
var obj = {name: "bar"};
var fooWithObjAndGlarb = foo.bind(obj, "glarb");
fooWithObjAndGlarb(); // "this.name = bar, arg = glarb"
```

This is called *binding* things (`obj` and the `"glarb"` argument) to `foo`.

Unlike `call`, since `bind` creates a new function, we can add arguments later:

```
function foo(arg) {
    console.log("this.name = " + this.name + ", arg = " + arg);
}
var obj = {name: "bar"};
var fooWithObj = foo.bind(obj);
fooWithObj("glarb"); // "this.name = bar, arg = glarb"
```

Okay, now we have all our working pieces. So what's happening in your code? Let's break it into parts:

```
// Get a reference to the `call` function from the `call` property
// on `Function`. The reason `Function` has a `call` property is that
// `Function` is, itself, a function, which means its prototype is
// `Function.prototype`, which has `call` on it.
var call = Function.call;

// Get a reference to the `slice` function from `Array.prototype`'s `slice` property:
var rawSlice = Array.prototype.slice;

// Create a *bound* copy of `call` that, when called, will call
// `call` with `this` set to `rawSlice`
var callBoundToSlice = call.bind(rawSlice);
```

(`callBoundToSlice` is just called `slice` in your question, but I'm using `callBoundToSlice` to avoid confusion.) Binding `rawSlice` to `call` was the first layer of `this` handling, determining what `call` will see as `this`. Calling `callBoundToSlice` will call `call` with `this` set to `rawSlice`. Then `call` will call the function it sees as `this` (`rawSlice`), using its first argument as the value for `this` during the call (the second layer of `this` handling) and passing on any further arguments.

So our `forEach` with a collection from `querySelectorAll` can now look like this:

```
callBoundToSlice(document.querySelectorAll("div")).forEach(function(div) {
    // Each div here
});
```

That passes the collecton returned by `querySelectorAll` into `callBoundToSlice`, which calls `call` with `this` as `rawSlice`, which calls `Array.prototype.slice` with `this` set to the collection. `Array.prototype.slice` uses `this` to copy the array.

---

All of that said, using `slice` to turn array-like objects into true arrays is a bit out of date. ES2015 introduces the [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method, which can be [shimmed/polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) on JavaScript engines that don't have it yet:

```
var divArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div"));
```

Comment: now this last Edit clears my Query. small correction in your answer - instead of "which calls call with this as the collection" it should be "which calls call with this as Array.prototype.slice".  Thank you very much

Comment: @Oxi: Good catch! Fixed. Great that you got the explanation so much that you were able to find an error in it! :-)

Comment: This is a great answer, for which you deserver more points, but this is usually library code that very few people deal with, so no wonder people don't slump over this answer by chance. We have this in the Sinon project, where it stumped me, even though I usually think I know `bind` and `call` pretty well: https://github.com/sinonjs/commons/blob/master/lib/prototypes/copy-prototype.js#L16. Thanks for enlightening the rest of us :-)