# a is a function, then what `a.call.call` really do?

Tags: javascript, call

[image]

These codes are run on chrome devtool.

It seems like `b.call`(same as `a.call.call`) is calling the first argument, which is a function, then pass the second argument as `this`.
If the first argument is not a function, then throw `not a function` error.

Can someone explain how `<Function>.call.call` work?

Comment: The "[Warlords of Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/419956)" a.k.a. "NullReference" isn't here yet, until that time your question is probably a bit too broad. Until then, I'd recommend other resources like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: @jeroen I already read that doc on MDN, but that just explains how `call` function work, and gives some examples. What I exactly ask here is `call.call`, whose behavior is different with `call`. And I can't get the works behind `call.call`.

Comment: The first argument to `.call()` is the object you want to set as the `this` value in the function that `call()` is to operate on.  If `call()` is itself the function to be operated on because you've chained `.call.call()` what does it do with the supplied `this` value? It assumes it's a function and tries to call it. But your last line of code doesn't pass a function, it passes an empty object.

Comment: P. S. Your `b` isn't related to `a` at all: `a` was just part of the mechanism by which you set `b` to refer to the `call` function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me show you an example.

```
function a() { console.log(1) }

function b() { console.log(2) }

a.call(b)    // 1

a.call.call(b)    // 2

a.call.call.call(b)    // 2
```

Why?

We know `a.call(b)` means invoke `a()` with **this** value `b`.

So that `a.call.call(b)` means invoke `Function.prototype.call()` with **this** value b, same as `Function.prototype.call.call(b)`.

But `Function.prototype.call.call()` is not an ordinary function Object. It can be invoked but it has no property. There's some **unique rules** to invoke it.

```
Function.prototype.call.call(a)    // 1

Function.prototype.call.call(b)    // 2
```

In fact, `Function.prototype.call.call(b)` is an Exotic Object, furthermore, a Bound Function Exotic Object.

- [Specification] A bound function is an exotic object that wraps another function object.
- [Specification] Calling a bound function generally results in a call of its wrapped function.

So that `Function.prototype.call.call(a)` simply means `a()`.

`a.call.call(x)` means invoke x, that is, `x()`.

- [Specification] In `Function.prototype.call(thisArg)`, if thisArg is undefined or null, it will be replaced by global object.

`a.call.call()` means `a.call.call(undefined)` means `a.call.call(window)` means invoke `window`.

Try to invoke `window` you'll get `Uncaught TypeError: window is not a function`, so try to invoke `a.call.call()` you'll get `Uncaught TypeError: a.call.call is not a function`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the basic stuff,

What is `.call` ?  its a function available inside `Function.prototype` .
So that it can be called on any function, thats exactly why you are able to call `a.call`.

Now, What does a `.call` do ?   it sets `this` context on the function you called `.call` on.   so in your case, when you call `a.call`  it can set a `this` context on function `a` (through the first parameter you pass to the `.call` function).

what is `this` inside the `.call` function ?  it is nothing but the function you called `.call` on(in your case `a`),
so for simplicity you assume, inside the `.call` it might be calling the function like `this()`
(and that is nothing but calling `a()`) - so far so good

**to your question**

```
a.call.call
```

what is happening here ?  the second `.call` (i am counting left to right) is calling first `.call` and setting `this` for the first `.call`, which is nothing but the first parameter, which is a function.

now first `.call` will call `this()` (remember this is set by the second `.call` and it is the first param you passed and this is a function).

i hope, i could explain what i intended to explain.

let me tell why you got confused with `a.call.call` . it is because you are thinking where did my function `a` gone in all this confusion ?
which is actually not involved as soon as yo call second `.call` (here `this` to first `.call` is coming from second `.call` which makes your function `a` obsolete in this case )

in you case `.call.call`   should have been called on `Function.prototype` or `Object` or any other function (remember `.call` is part of `Function.prototype` and can be called on any function)

so you should have done

```
Function.prototype.call.call(...)
```

or even

```
Object.call.call(...)
```

Now i was confused about these thing last week(not `.call.call` but `.call.bind`), i asked a question here, and somebody explained it to me in very detailed, you can find it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807192/understanding-function-call-bind-step-by-step)

i tried to answer from my understanding from the question i asked.

**after all this is what SO is for**

UPDATE:

you question "It seems like b.call(same as a.call.call) is calling the first argument, which is a function, then pass the second argument as this. If the first argument is not a function, then throw not a function error."

**your assumption is correct here**

Comment: thanks! I will read your answer and links twice to get some ideas.

Comment: and your assumption is correct  and, i updated my answer to capture that

Comment: Please relate this with an example that will be easy to understand.